# how to display array values inside view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i am trying to display an array inside a view but  it says undefined index this is the code inside the controller

```
   $collection = [];

    foreach($drugss as $r){
        $collection[] = DB::table('drugs')->where('id', $r['drug_id'])->get();
    }

     // dd($collection);
    return view('billing')->withDrugs($collection)->withPending($pending_orders);
```

and wen i type dd($collection) it shows that all the objects inside the array but i cant access them inside the view

this is the view

```
                @foreach ($drugs as $drug)

                <span >{{ $drug['generic_name']}}</span> 
               @endforeach
```

this is the array collection that i am sending to the view

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the `dd` output tells you is that each item in the collection is another collection containing a single element: the array.

This is because `->get()` will always return a collection.

What you have:

```
 $collection
  - 0: Collection
     - 0:  [ ...first array ... ]
  - 1: Collection
     - 0: [ ...second array ... ]
  ...
```

What you expect:

```
 $collection
  - 0: [ ...first array ... ]
  - 1: [ ...second array ... ]
  ...
```

You could use `first()` to obtain the array instead of the collection:

```php
$collection[] = DB::table('drugs')->where('id', $r['drug_id'])->first();
```

---

As a more performant alternative, you could retrieve all the drugs directly with a single query by identifying all your ids before performing the query:

```php
$drugsId = array_map(function ($r) { return $r['drug_id']; }, $drugss);
$collection = DB::table('drugs')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i understand but now it says Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in the view

Comment: i understand what you saying but i want duplicated records to get in the table for examlpe (wherein [1,3,5,1] ) that way it doesnt work to use whereIn

Comment: @BrawRajab Then change `$drug['generic_name']` to `$drug->generic_name`, or define a `Drug` model and don't use `DB::table()`. Models instances (from `Drug::where(...)` can use `[]` or `->` access, but `stdClass` objects (from `DB::table()`) cannot.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you have an array of collections. I am not sure why you chose such a strange structure. With your array structure, you will have to call another foreach loop inside your foreach loop to iterate over your collections arrays.

I think what you really wanted was to get a collection of Drugs which have some ids.

I would create an id array first and then get all the Drugs which have one of the ids in the ids array:

```
$ids = [];

 foreach($drugss as $r){
        array_push($ids, $r['drug_id']);
   }
$drugs = DB::table('drugs')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

**@edit If you want duplicate entries (assuming you have a Drug model):**

```
$drugs = collect(new Drug);
foreach($drugss as $r){
      $drugs->add(Drug::find($r['drug_id']));
}
```

Otherwise you can do something like that:

```
$drugs = [];
foreach($drugss as $r){
      array_push($drugs, Drug::find($r['drug_id']));
}
```

Comment: i understand what you saying but i want duplicated records to get in the table for examlpe (wherein [1,3,5,1] ) that way it doesnt work